# Pointwise convergence and absolute convergence in $L^1([0,1])$ imply uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider a pointwise convergent series $\sum f_n$ of continuous (hence also bounded) functions on $[0,1]$, which is absolutely convergent in $L^1$. Isn't the series also uniformly convergent in this case?

(Basically I want to infer that $\sum f_n$ is continuous.)

Comment: Certainly not.  See if you can find a counterexample using piecewise linear functions.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you! Sorry I forgot to mention the additional assumption of pointwise convergence.

Comment: False even with the condition of pointwise convergence.

Comment: I'm not sure about this,but how about $f_n(x)=x^{n^2}.$ $||f_n(x)||={1\over{n^2 +1}}$

Comment: @Srinivas K: I think that works. The behavior near $x=1$ makes the series fail to be uniformly convergent, right?

Comment: @Shalop It cannot be uniformly convergent. If it was uniformly convergent, the sum would be continuous , which is not true. I was doubtful only about the absolute convergence.

Comment: Yes, absolute convergence is obvious, since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2+1} < \infty$. But why is the limit function discontinuous? It is continuous on $[0,1)$, and on $[0,1]$ if we consider the extended real line.

Comment: @Shalop Sorry. I just forgot about the $\sum$ and was thinking of $lim f_n$. I really don't know what te limit function is.

Comment: I don't know what the limit function is either, but in any case your example works because the difference in sup between any two successive partial sums is 1, so it cannot converge uniformly. Nice example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, consider the function $f_n(x)=2n(n+1) \cdot $dist$\big(x \; , \; [0,\frac{1}{n+1}] \cup [\frac{1}{n},1]\big)$. Then $f_n$ is a "hat shaped function" which takes the value $0$ outside of the interval $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$, and achieves its maximum value of $1$ at the midpoint of the interval $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$.

Then $\sum f_n$ converges absolutely in $L^1$, but fails to converge uniformly, and in fact, the limit function is discontinuous at $0$.

Note: dist$\big(x \; , \; [0,\frac{1}{n+1}] \cup [\frac{1}{n},1]\big) := \inf \{ |x-y| : 0 \leq y \leq \frac{1}{n+1} $ or $ \frac{1}{n} \leq y \leq 1 \}$

Comment: Thank you. As I noted above, in fact I'm considering an everywhere convergent series.

Comment: $\sum f_n$ does indeed converge pointwise, right?